# z-index attribute not working on container with image

Tags: css

do not know what I might be doing wrong, I tried to put it this way:

```
.container-image{
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Dl8UBO7.png');
    width: 226px;
    height: 169px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20; // dont work
}

.container-image img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    top: 13px;
    width: 199px;
    height: 141px;
    z-index: 10; // dont work
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfmRK/)

I need the image is behind the edge (.container-image)

Comment: this border is complicated to do only with CSS

Comment: Oh I see you have that thing there so it's not all the way solid sorry

Comment: You will have to separate them then stack them http://jsfiddle.net/HfmRK/3/

Comment: z-index is hierarchical, so the parent z-index is cast onto the child elements as the new base-line. A child element therefore cannot have an overall z-index that is 'smaller' than the parent. The solution would be to wrap a container around the two elements you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a container around the border div and the image. http://jsfiddle.net/7fqAu/2/

```
<div class='example'>
    <div class="container-image"></div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/T0KMwIs.jpg">
</div>
```

---

```
body {
    background: red;
}
.container-image {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Dl8UBO7.png');
    width: 226px;
    height: 169px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
.example {
    width: 226px;
    height: 169px;
    position: relative;
}
.example img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    top: 13px;
    width: 199px;
    height: 141px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the border image to `.container-image:after` instead of as a background to `.container-image` - no need for z-index at all then.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pET96/1/)